# How to check if user is authenticated on SvelteKit

Tags: typescript, authentication, jwt, svelte, sveltekit

I would like to check if the user is logged in using the `access_token` cookie which is a JWT token

I tried to add a file `hooks.server.ts` with a request inside to check the route `/api/token/user/me` which allows me to return the user information and then store them in `event.locals.user` (knowing that `/api/token/user/me` comes from an external API that I connected with a proxy) but I get this error

> Error: Cannot use relative URL (/api/token/user/me) with global fetch — use `event.fetch` instead: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/web-standards#fetch-apis

```
// src/hooks.server.ts
import type { Handle } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export const handle: Handle = async ({ event, resolve }) => {
    const cookies = event.cookies;
    const access_token = cookies.get('access_token');

    if (access_token) {
        const response = await fetch(`/api/token/user/me`, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`
            }
        });
        const user = await response.json();

        event.locals.user = user;
    }
    return await resolve(event);
};
```

```
// src/routes/+layout.server.ts
export const load = async ({ locals }) => {
    return {
        user: locals.user
    };
};
```

I don't know if this is the right practice to do what I want to do, but I hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: Have you read the documentation *linked in the error*?

Comment: when I replace `fetch` by `event.fetch` i have an infinite loading...

Answer (score 0):

> when I replace `fetch` by `event.fetch` i have an infinite loading

The hook will run for that request as well, causing yet another request and so on.

You will have to either prevent the request if the current request matches that route or extract the logic that happens in that endpoint to a regular separate function, so you do not need `fetch` to call it.

To check the route/URL you can probably add something like:

```js
if (access_token && event.route.id != '/api/token/user/me') {
  // [fetch etc.]
}
// or
if (access_token && event.url.pathname != '/api/token/user/me') {
  // [fetch etc.]
}
```

(The route ID should generally be preferable, especially if there are parameters it will be easier to match, as it will contain their placeholders instead. It probably also does not contain the [base](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-paths-base).)